# Uppercase url in fromHTML results in crash

Tags: android

Why does this crash when touched:
`text_link.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href="HTTP://WWW.GOOGLE.COM">Test</a>"));`

But this works fine:
`text_link.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>"));`

The only difference is the url in the first is UPPERCASE and the bottom is not.

Answer (score -2):

Domain names are technically all lowercase, fromHtml don't lower the case for you.

Comment: That's not true, domain names are *usually* lowercase, but don't have to be.